# Sitecore-NextJS - how do I redirect a page with a querystring to not have one?

Tags: next.js, sitecore

I have  a page in Sitecore

`htttp://server/MyPage?id=ABC or htttp://server/MyPage?name=PQR&id=ABC`

I want to redirect to

`http://server/MyPage/ABC`

I need to do this through rewrites

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best you can do without something more fancy to remove 'id' from the resulting URL parameters. If you really do need a rewrite, there's a similar config for rewriting. In your next.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/MyPage',
        destination: '/MyPage/:id',
        permanent: false,
        has: [
          {
            type: 'query',
            key: 'id',
            value: '(?<id>.*)'
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  },
async rewrites() {
  return [
    {
      source: '/MyPage',
      destination: '/MyPage/:id',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'query',
          key: 'id',
          value: '(?<id>.*)'
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
}
};
```